# A Completely Different Kind of Reef

Tags: biology, evolution, environment, underwater

In this scenario, corals, sponges and bryozoans have been extinct for 65 million years.  In their place as reefbuilders are echinoderms, bivalves, barnacles and worms of the infraclass *canalipalpata*.

As reefbuilders, what advantage or edge would any of them have over coral?

Comment: Advantage: they exist. How do you measure the advantage or edge something has over a creature that's been extinct for 65 million years?

Comment: @Samuel Michael Crichton wrote two books on it.

Comment: To turn it around, we can pretty clearly see that, on a level playing field, your putative survivors in fact _do not_ have any advantage in reef-building over the extinct species.  If they did, we would see barnacle reefs rather than coral reefs today.

Answer (score 2):

Reefs would have a hugely different look.  Coral is kind of a 'growing stone' in that the bones of the coral stay behind and continue to support the growth of more coral and other life forms on top of it, in some ways like a tree, growing new wood on the outside.

Barnacles, bivalves and other mollusks tend to build beaches and limestone bed rock.  Barnacles would be a pretty slow way to build a reef, since for another layer to grow the previous layer will have to die.  Coral is a much simpler life form than even barnacles.

Coral while having spaces in its structure are very small compared to mollusks what have a 'living space' inside the hard shell.  So a reef would be more likely to collapse in on itself periodically because they just aren't designed for that kind of weight.

So mollusks would be a very poor reef creator.

Comment: Tell that to the rudists.

Comment: @JohnWDailey I had to look that up.  Very interesting.  Learned something new today, something like that might not do a bad job of creating a reef.

Answer (score 1):

In 65 million years, it is possible that one or more of the species named could have evolved to take the place of corals, but there would have to be some sort of evolutionary advantage to do so, and obviously the base creature would need to change their lifestyle to replicate corals.

Barnacles would seem to be the best bet to evolve into a coral analogue. The key change will be to move from building 2D structures on surfaces to building 3D structures. This might be forced on them as competition for available surfaces becomes more intense. Barnacles of different species might begin in a competitive relationship, attempting to carpet over each other to secure the surface. Gradually, since carpeting a surface already covered with barnacles will be incomplete and leave a multitude of gaps, species will become more cooperative rather than competitive in order to create the sorts of 3D structures which maximise food gathering surfaces, spaces for symbionts to live and so on. Sixty Five million years is a long time in evolutionary time, so if a niche becomes open, eventually it will be filled.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that any of them would have an advantage over corals when it comes to building reefs. Perhaps they could manage to build some, but it would be hard.

[**Echinoderms**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Echinoderm)

Coral create coral reefs by secreting calcium carbonate<sup>[[1]](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coral#Reefs)</sup>. Echinoderms have partial skeletons composed of calcite<sup>[[2]](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Echinoderm#Skin_and_skeleton)</sup>, which is, for our purposes, the same thing. Echinoderms can lose limbs ad regenerate them so it is possible that you could create structures with some of the skeletal material from disused limbs. A stretch? Yes. But not impossible.

The thing is, echinoderms like to live on the seabed. This is not conducive to reef-building. The raw materials are there, but the ability to assemble them may not be.

[**Bivalves**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bivalvia)

Bivalves are also composed in part of calcium carbonate<sup>[[3]](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bivalvia),1</sup>, like echinoderms and corals. They are, however - to quote Wikipedia - "sedentary", preferring to stay where they are on the seafloor. Once again, it appears like it would be difficult to create complex three-dimensional reef-like structures out of them.

[**Barnacles**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barnacle)

Barnacles, too, do not move<sup>[[4]](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barnacle)</sup>, meaning that their placement for reef-building must be crucial. That said, they grow *en masse* in large groups, making it especially easy for them to take over large areas. They can quickly cover an area in themselves. They are made of - yes, you guessed it - calcite, the same building material as corals. They seem to be the best bet so far to replace corals.

[**Worms**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Worm)

Worms have soft bodies, and are invertebrates. They would not be good reef-builders.

---

<sup>1 I'm sensing a pattern here. I assume you already knew about composition.</sup>

Comment: "Worms have soft bodies, and are invertebrates. They would not be good reef-builders."  Tell that to the tube worms.